# Alternatives to -Info class name suffix

Tags: java, naming-conventions, code-cleanup

I've been reading *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin, and came across the infamous statement:

> Avoid words like Manager, Processor, Data, or *Info* in the name of a
>   class.

So, naturally, I've tried to factor `-Info` out of one of my class names. Now, I've seen all sorts of StackOverflow questions asking about what to do to in the case of `-Manager` or `-Processor`. I've seen comments suggesting that they can't think of a time when `-Data` would be a good class name. Well, in my opinion, `-Data` and `-Info` seem harder to factor out. Especially, for example in the below class.

I have a `Server` class like the following:

```
public class Server {
    //What I would call ServerInfo
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int port;
    private int connections;
    private int maxConnections;
    private int status;

    //Bunch of members that aren't ServerInfo, for example:
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, File> files = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, File>();
    private List<String> filePaths = new List<String>();
    /* ... */

    public void start() { /* ... */ }
    public void stop()  { /* ... */ }
}
```

There is a `HashMap` stored of these Server's information like the following on another remote server:

```
public class ServerMap {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Server> serverMap = /* ... */;
}
```

But, this `HashMap` only needs to know about what I have said is `ServerInfo` above. It doesn't need to waste memory by storing a bunch of variables it will never use. So, a Data class is needed to house these variables.

```
public class ServerInfo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int port;
    private int connections;
    private int maxConnections;
    private int status;
}
```

And `ServerMap` now becomes `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ServerInfo>`.

The problem is that this obviously violates the rule from *Clean Code*. I could change `-Info` to some synonym, but then, isn't that not really fixing the problem? For example, I could call it `ServerDetails` but I fail to see how that is any different than `ServerData` or `ServerInfo`.

I could redefine `Server` in a different namespace, and give it just these members, but that seems even more confusing.

What is the ***best practice*** solution to this?

Comment: If the "Bunch of members that aren't ServerInfo" are not neccessarily in used then why you put them in the `Server`? Can you give more example about them?

Comment: @Genzer They are used by `Server`. They aren't used by the map that contains information about each `Server`. Only the variables in `ServerInfo` need to be known/stored by the `ServerMap`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the point of the statement is to avoid using such overloaded terms like -Data and -Info when it comes to class naming.  I don't think it's inappropriate to use something like ServerDetails for the object you're naming.  After all, that's what they are isn't it?

If ServerDetails is too generic, ask yourself what kind of info/details they are...  In this case they all look network or connection related.  How about ServerConnectionProperties or a something similar?

Use the guidelines the author sets forth as exactly that; guidelines.  Just keep in mind that there are tons of people with tons of opinions and very few of them apply 100% of the time.  You'll go mad trying to apply every 'best practice' to the letter.

Comment: This seems very reasonable to me. The author stated it with such absoluteness, that I felt like it was some rule that needed to be followed 100% of the time - as if there was some inherent design flaw in my code since I couldn't find a way to follow it.

Comment: I can't fault you there.  Every time I get into something new I'm always digging for the 'Best Practice' guidelines to keep me on the path and it leads to lots of head banging.  I try to do some research, choose a path, and go from there.  Though admittedly I find myself going down the rabbit hole at times too.

Comment: What do you think about `ServerState` or `ServerSnapshot`, as it is kind of a snapshot/state of the `Server` at a given moment in time.

Comment: If that's what it captures, they sound Ok to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking at the refactoring the wrong way. They correct name (in my opinion) for `ServerInfo` would be `Server` because that is what the server actually is. When we deal with OOP the "base" object is the object with the data. For example, we wouldnt call a class with username, email, and password `UserInfo` or `UserData` because the data is implied by the fact that its a class with members. 
Obviously, there are some exceptions to this rule. It is common practice to have a `ProfileData` object to contain certain less important information for Users.

There are two ways I can think of how I personally would re-factor this server problem.
One is I would rename the base (serverInfo) to `Server` and the higher level object to something else like `ServerCommands` (its hard for me to find a fitting name because I do not know everthing the class does)

My next suggestion is based on the idea of 'generalization'. The biggest reason we dont want to name classes this why is because it generalizes implied aspects of programming. Just about all classes tend to have "info" and "data" associated. What is this info or data? I would like to quote from the SO subject discussing "helper" and "manager" re-factors.

> Reason: A class name like "ThreadHelper" makes people wonder why it's
>   needed and why it cannot just be part of the "Thread" class. Is it
>   actually an adapter or a decorator? If so, name it that way. Is class
>   "Thread" taking too much responsibility already? If so, refactor and
>   give the new class a meaningful name. "Helper" says nothing about what
>   it's doing or how it's helping.

Its all about what is the classes actual intended purpose. If I see a class called serverInfo I might or might not understand what the info is. 
I personally would name it `ServerProperties`. It might sound like it is just a synonym of info, but its actually more specific. When we think of properties, we think of "one time set up" details that do not change. (or if they do change, it is because we are changing settings). You could also call it `ServerSettings` but I personally like properties more.

Comment: They aren't one time setup details that do not change, though. For example, `connections` would change as more connections come in. One property I excluded (by accident) was `status` which would say if the server is Online, Offline, Locked, Loading, etc. This would change as well. This information is only a small portion of the overall `Server` object, and it is this information only that needs to be stored in the `ServerMap` rather than storing the entire `Server` object. `Settings` and `Propeties` both convey a context other than what the intent would be. Perhaps now you can suggest others?

Comment: As I am looking at these details, what I would do in this situation (now that I see more details) is make serverInfo something like `BasicServer` and then the Server class something like `ServerWithFiles` or `FileServer` or things such like that. (or something that reflects the extra data it contains) You could even make `FileServer` extend `BasicServer` So that later on you could create a different server class with different extended members

Comment: And then store instances of `BasicServer` in the `ServerMap`? The `ServerMap` lives on a different box, so, the instances of `BasicServer` that would be live there would not be references to the instance that lives elsewhere. That's why it is important for this class that is contained within `ServerMap` to contain only the pertinent data that is needed. I'm leaning towards naming it `ServerState` now. Thanks for the response!